# How to interpret mwaits output

Tags: c#, locking, sos, sosex, windb

I am trying to understand how can I use mwaits command things like  type of lock, lock owner etc. I know that some of this could be done via sos commands but how can  I use  information below that 
I am getting with sosex mwaits command.

```
0:006> !mwaits
Examining SyncBlocks...
Scanning for ReaderWriterLock instances...
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLock locks...
Scanning for ReaderWriterLockSlim instances...
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLockSlim locks...
Examining CriticalSections...
Scanning for threads waiting on SyncBlocks...
Scanning for threads waiting on ReaderWriterLock locks...
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
Scanning for threads waiting on ReaderWriterLocksSlim locks...
Scanning for threads waiting on CriticalSections...
Scanning threads for waits on unknown locks...

ClrThread  DbgThread  OsThread    LockType    Lock              LockLevel
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0xac       88         0x1a4       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x116      49         0x2e0       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        1          0x3d0       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x111      46         0x4ac       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x57f      338        0x538       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x598      216        0x590       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4ed      273        0x68c       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x105      42         0x710       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xbc       76         0x8b0       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        117        0x8bc       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x59d      223        0x904       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xae       86         0x918       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xb4       80         0x9a4       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x559      238        0xa38       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x359      180        0xa44       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x32e      382        0xa74       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x59b      220        0xa88       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        102        0xab8       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x59a      219        0xac4       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x32d      383        0xad4       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x34f      360        0xaec       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x25       114        0xb30       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x551      295        0xb34       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        106        0xb64       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x592      212        0xca0       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xd1       38         0xcf4       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x10e      44         0xde0       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x32c      384        0xdf4       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x15       21         0xe5c       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4d9      293        0xe64       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x55c      242        0xe68       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x57e      339        0xee0       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xb1       83         0xef4       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x56e      318        0xf54       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xd4       101        0xf78       <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xc3       69         0x1030      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xb0       84         0x1058      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x42a      196        0x10c8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x58f      215        0x10e0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4cd      349        0x10fc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x32f      381        0x1114      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x232      121        0x1170      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4a5      255        0x1194      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xab       89         0x1210      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x125      62         0x1220      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x58c      291        0x12a4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x500      209        0x12a8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4e6      266        0x12ac      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xd3       109        0x12b4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4f2      278        0x12b8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x59f      224        0x12c4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x436      158        0x12d8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x10d      43         0x12f4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        115        0x1334      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2        6          0x1338      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x563      306        0x1348      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xc        15         0x1350      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x119      52         0x135c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        4          0x1390      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x357      142        0x13ac      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x594      211        0x13bc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x118      51         0x13f0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x561      304        0x13fc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x40c      156        0x1414      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x11a      53         0x1418      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x336      374        0x1424      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xf9       40         0x1454      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x352      357        0x1464      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x1f       30         0x14f4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x3fe      176        0x14f8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x444      169        0x1504      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x565      308        0x1514      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4a7      178        0x1528      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x334      376        0x1540      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x5a6      198        0x154c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x34c      363        0x1594      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x11f      58         0x159c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x10f      45         0x15c8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x56d      317        0x1634      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x11b      54         0x1690      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xaa       90         0x1754      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x580      337        0x1848      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x442      146        0x1878      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        7          0x1898      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x341      370        0x18a0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x593      210        0x18e0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x585      344        0x1994      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x8b       120        0x19a8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2f6      177        0x1a78      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x55a      237        0x1aa4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4d3      346        0x1ac4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4dd      243        0x1ac8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x566      309        0x1aec      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x569      312        0x1b14      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4c9      353        0x1b18      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x114      100        0x1b1c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x371      162        0x1b30      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xbd       75         0x1b38      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x57c      332        0x1b6c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xbb       77         0x1b80      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x333      377        0x1bac      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x573      323        0x1bb8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4cc      350        0x1bc8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x590      214        0x1bf0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x53e      253        0x1bf4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x350      359        0x1c0c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x128      65         0x1c44      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x1        0          0x1c4c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x578      328        0x1c60      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4f7      284        0x1c6c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4a6      257        0x1c7c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x351      358        0x1c9c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xa2       98         0x1ca8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xa        13         0x1cc0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xc6       66         0x1ce8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4c2      166        0x1cf0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x437      159        0x1d20      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xbf       73         0x1d60      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4d6      137        0x1d8c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x42b      197        0x1d98      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4df      161        0x1dcc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x117      50         0x1dd4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xa3       97         0x1de4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x541      250        0x1df0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x126      63         0x1e40      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xa5       95         0x1e50      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x542      249        0x1e7c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4ea      269        0x1ea0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x571      321        0x1eac      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4f0      276        0x1ec8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xa9       91         0x1eec      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x557      240        0x1ef8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4e0      260        0x1f2c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x57a      330        0x1f68      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x17       23         0x1f78      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x36d      170        0x1f7c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xa4       96         0x1f80      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x486      187        0x1f8c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x115      99         0x1fb4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4f6      283        0x1fe8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x127      64         0x2010      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x55e      301        0x2030      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4eb      271        0x2034      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2ba      389        0x2078      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4ec      272        0x2080      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xc5       67         0x20b4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4d0      342        0x20bc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x34a      364        0x20c0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x11c      55         0x20e0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        3          0x20f8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x331      379        0x2100      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xcd       36         0x2104      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x1c       26         0x2118      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x5b4      234        0x2128      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4b0      167        0x2144      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4f9      286        0x214c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xa7       93         0x2178      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x11e      57         0x2198      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4e8      268        0x21b4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x581      336        0x21c0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4f4      280        0x21f4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xd0       79         0x221c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xb2       82         0x2238      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4        20         0x2250      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xc1       71         0x2254      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x121      60         0x2270      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        2          0x22a4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4b5      191        0x22b8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x18       24         0x22d4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x54a      244        0x22ec      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x335      375        0x230c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x354      355        0x232c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x54c      334        0x2350      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x367      181        0x2360      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xba       78         0x2364      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        103        0x236c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xa8       92         0x2388      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x574      324        0x238c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x54d      241        0x2394      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xcc       37         0x23a4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        118        0x23ac      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xf7       39         0x23d8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x337      373        0x23f8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x488      201        0x2408      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x9b       111        0x241c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4cf      348        0x2420      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x59c      221        0x243c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x11d      56         0x2444      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4e4      264        0x245c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xce       34         0x24b4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xaf       85         0x24c8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x496      163        0x24dc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xd        16         0x2530      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x112      47         0x2534      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x564      307        0x2544      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4c1      182        0x256c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x23       113        0x2574      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4e1      261        0x258c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x5b5      235        0x25c0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x568      311        0x25c4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xb3       81         0x25d8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4e7      267        0x25e0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x3e7      340        0x25e4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x348      366        0x25ec      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x7        29         0x25f0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x16       22         0x2638      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        105        0x2640      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        104        0x2658      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x40d      168        0x265c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x56a      314        0x2678      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        5          0x269c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4e3      263        0x26dc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x458      195        0x2720      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xfd       41         0x272c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4cb      351        0x273c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x554      300        0x2754      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x347      367        0x2764      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4f5      281        0x27a0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        107        0x27a8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        12         0x27cc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xc0       72         0x27d8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x579      329        0x27dc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x61       33         0x27f4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4d5      136        0x27fc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x50d      206        0x2820      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4e2      262        0x2860      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x546      246        0x2874      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x33e      369        0x2884      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x345      190        0x289c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x9d       110        0x28b4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x562      305        0x28b8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xa6       94         0x28bc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x553      297        0x28d4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x36e      149        0x28d8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4ca      352        0x28ec      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xb        14         0x28f0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x5a2      227        0x28f4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x1a       25         0x2908      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x356      143        0x2918      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x22       112        0x2930      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x510      207        0x2964      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x570      320        0x2968      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xc2       70         0x2978      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        116        0x29b0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4ef      275        0x29dc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x1e       28         0x29fc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4fb      287        0x2a18      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x122      61         0x2a40      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x1d       27         0x2a44      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xf        17         0x2a50      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xbe       74         0x2a5c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x10       18         0x2a78      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x47c      183        0x2a88      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xad       87         0x2a98      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xc4       68         0x2abc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x113      48         0x2b00      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x120      59         0x2b2c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xb8       193        0x2b48      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x9e       108        0x2b60      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x33b      372        0x2bdc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x0        8          0x2bf4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x409      188        0x2c20      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x49c      199        0x2c68      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x589      333        0x2ca0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x423      165        0x2d34      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x50c      205        0x2d3c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x34d      362        0x2d80      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0xe        185        0x2dac      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4d1      347        0x2dd8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2e1      122        0x2df4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2e2      123        0x2df8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2e3      124        0x2dfc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2e5      125        0x2e04      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x543      248        0x2e0c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2ee      126        0x2e28      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2ef      127        0x2e2c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2f0      128        0x2e30      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2f1      129        0x2e34      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x5a5      230        0x2e38      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2f2      130        0x2e40      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2f4      131        0x2e48      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x55f      302        0x2ea8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x544      313        0x2eb4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4c4      299        0x2ecc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x56b      315        0x2ed8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4f8      285        0x2ee0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x587      345        0x2f28      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4c8      354        0x2f6c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x343      368        0x2f70      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x555      256        0x2f74      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x548      245        0x2fb0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x355      144        0x2fc8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x330      380        0x2fd4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4d8      294        0x2ff0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x2f8      160        0x303c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x5a7      231        0x305c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4fa      288        0x306c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x57b      331        0x312c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x540      251        0x3170      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x41f      147        0x3194      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x400      173        0x31ac      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x404      200        0x31c8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x576      326        0x31d4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4d7      258        0x31e0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x37a      192        0x31f0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x54b      292        0x31f8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x556      236        0x3230      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x3ef      132        0x3238      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x3f0      133        0x323c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x3f1      134        0x3240      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x575      325        0x3278      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x15e      189        0x32c8      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4ee      274        0x32f4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x55d      172        0x3300      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4fe      140        0x3304      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x413      179        0x334c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x552      296        0x3374      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4de      259        0x343c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x5b3      233        0x344c      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4b3      153        0x3450      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x432      174        0x3460      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x3f7      157        0x3478      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4b4      152        0x3484      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x3fd      186        0x34c4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4e5      265        0x34dc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x5a3      228        0x34fc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x443      145        0x3510      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x373      194        0x3520      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4ce      135        0x3544      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x3f2      154        0x3554      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x48b      175        0x3598      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x4f1      277        0x35a0      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x349      365        0x35cc      <Unknown>   0000000000000000                  
0x403      151        0x35d4      <Unknown>   0000000000000000
```

Comment: What symptoms are you troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the LockType is UNKNOWN, then these are probably things like event handles.  To investigate, look at each thread's callstack.

Comment: Basically investigation an application for high memory usage that also seen to hang on some threads. Most of the threads showing System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative on top of stack. So mwaits is not useful for any particular scenaiors? Can I get any useful information out of it?

Comment: !mwaits is useful if the locks are CRITICAL_SECTIONS, SyncBlock locks, ReaderWriterLocks, ReaderWriterLockSlims.  Basically, it's any managed lock + critical section.  !mwaits is not useful for events, threads and other kernel handles.

Comment: I should have said that !mwaits is useful if threads are waiting on any of the objects I described, but not if the thread is waiting on a event, thread or other kernel object.